# JDBC in Android with SSL Certificates

Tags: java, android, postgresql, ssl, jdbc

I am able to connect to postgresql in my Android App using JDBC:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String ip = "HOST_IP";
    private static String port = "5432";
    private static String Classes = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static String database = "DATABASE_NAME";
    private static String username = "USERNAME";
    private static String password = "PASSWORD";
    private static String url = "jdbc:postgresql://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+database;

    private Connection connection = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
    }

    public void start(View view) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
      
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            Class.forName(Classes);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,password);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Class fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connected no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine. But how can i manage it to use SSL (verify-ca)? I have all 3 certificates (server, client and key) in .pem format. Where should i store these certificates and how to use wit JDBC?

Comment: Just a heads-up, irrelevant to the question: if you are using JDBC directly from the client like this, any user who can get hold of you app and is willing to put some minimal effort, can see the connection properties to your database, including the password. BEWARE!

Comment: If you don't use the database user and authentication system for limiting access your app should perform database queries not directly to avoid the problem outlined by Nikos: Set-up a web server that takes e.g. HTTP REST calls and for each API performs the appropriate SQL query. This REST interface can then be limited to authenticated users (own user management) and SQL queries that do not harm the database (only those needed by your app).

Comment: It will be for a company and the credentials should be prompted at start. App will not be public and only run on some devices from company without other apps. Its only a sample connection here.

Comment: What you need is the root cert.  It sounds like you aren't using client certs, so no one needs that.  The server cert (and server key) is needed by the server, not by the client.  Where to store it and how to override is described https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html